# Adding wlan0 to xenbr0

Tags: networking, wifi, xen, bridge

I'm setting up xen on debian to do some testing and having problems with the bridge.

I would like to use wlan0 as the bridge, but can't seem to get this working. Currently I have tried this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-ssid "myssid"
    wpa-psk mypasscode

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports wlan0
```

"But then it displays: can't add wlan0 to bridge xenbr0: Operation not supported"

It this even possible?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Xen over KVM?

Comment: Have you had a look at this ? - https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC

Answer (score 3):

The error message probably means that your wlan0 interface is not up.

Possible solution:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces  
auto xenbr0  
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0 wlan0

iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-ssid "myssid"
    wpa-psk mypasscode
    post-up brctl addif xenbr0 wlan0
```

On the last line you add your `wlan0`interface to `xenbr0`.